# Cannot insert duplicate key row in object with unique index 'in_name'

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I get this error: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object with unique index 'in_name'
What can be the problem?

```
var ing = (from x in db.tblTable where x.ing_name == ing_name select x);
var ing1 = ing.First();
ing1.ing_name = ing1.ing_name + " (" + FormatC(ing_brand) + ")";
db.SaveChanges();
```

And here is FormatC:

```
public static string FormatC(string str)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
            return str.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + "" + str.Substring(1).ToLower();
        else
            return "";
    }
```

Comment: SQL has a unique index or unique key constraint (`in_name`) which is likely enforcing the uniqueness of `ing_name` on your table. You will need to update the existing row, or remove the unique index.

Comment: @nonnb OMG I can't believe I didn't see it.

Comment: Turns out that SQL Server, by default, sets indexed fields to allow only unique values. To check this, open the table in Design and select "Manage Indexes and Keys" option. Select the index/key listed and check the appropriate Yes/No drop down for the "Is Unique" property.  https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/cannot-insert-duplicate-key-row-in-object-with-unique-index-on-duplicate-foreing-key

Answer (score -1):

Got this answer from - https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/cannot-insert-duplicate-key-row-in-object-with-unique-index-on-duplicate-foreing-key

Turns out that SQL Server, by default, sets indexed fields to allow only unique values. To check this, open the table in Design and select "Manage Indexes and Keys" option. Select the index/key listed and check the appropriate Yes/No drop down for the "Is Unique" property.

Comment: Not true. Creating a unique index is a deliberate action. Forget the unique keyword in the create script or don't tick the checkbox in SSMS and the index is not unique.